# NLayers Architecture - Does User Session is CrossCutting component? How could we implement it?

Tags: session, architecture, dns, layer

It's supposed we have N Layers Architecture (Example: Presentation, Domain, Persistence).
Presentation layer is Web application, but we have to bear in mind that we could want to reuse Domain and Persistence for another Presentation Layer (like Web Service, or Window app).

Domain must implement all business logic taking into account Users permissions. Now my question is, how Domain knows about user session and which is the user who is calling to his services?

My Domain Service interfaces (or contracts) in all his methods will include "UserId" input parameter provided by Presentation Layer (Domain should be trust in Presentation Layer):

- GetProfileInfo(userId)
- GetUserPendingOrders(userId)

OR.. Does User Session should be a CrossCutting component? If it does, domain would know which user is calling his service so the interface will be:

- GetProfileInfo()
- GetUserPendingOrders()

How could we implement it? Does exists some Design Pattern?

Do we must save user session in Storage? or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A User Session in the classic web-based context is something only the web server knows about.

You can have the concept of a User Session within your application (as just another kind of domain object, with it's own data repository, etc) but you'd just want to be careful to not bind / tightly-couple that in any way to the web servers concept of a session.

The same would go for other kinds of application (WinForms, etc).

The idea of a UserId is unrelated to user session; sure a user might use the system (creating a new session, and you might be able to tie the two things together.  (Your examples above made me wonder if you had confused them).

**Is it a cross cutting concern?**

If you establish a User Session as a formal domain object - then the answer is "yes" because domain objects (or the concepts they represent) are cross-cutting **but** not in the same sense that logging or error handling are.

Otherwise if user sessions are nothing more that (for example) web server based sessions then the answer is "no", it's a concept specific to the presentation layer - running on the web-server.

Then there's a third option, a sort of half way house: you might pass around a users SessionID just like you'd pass around any other primitive piece of data - but never actually having a User Session domain object.  You just have to be careful here; for example one kind of web-server might use a GUID, another might use an int or a string - so be careful how you go.